# zuul proxy always giving 401 unauthorized

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am using zuul proxy for routes and have added JWT authentication for the same. I have specified the APIs for with authorisation is to be skipped for example (/auth) but i am not able to call the same as I am getting 401 for the permitted URLs as well.

Following are the code snippet.

Class implementing WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(jwtConfig), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/ping").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
```

And also my application.properties file looks as mentioned below

```
server.port=8762
spring.application.name=zuul-server
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/

# A prefix that can added to beginning of all requests.
zuul.prefix=/api

# Disable accessing services using service name (i.e. gallery-service).
# They should be only accessed through the path defined below.
zuul.ignored-services=*

# Map paths to services
zuul.routes.user-service.path=/users/**
zuul.routes.user-service.service-id=user-service
zuul.routes.user-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie

# Map path to auth service
zuul.routes.auth-service.path=/auth/**
zuul.routes.auth-service.service-id=auth-service
zuul.routes.auth-service.strip-prefix=false
# Exclude authorization from sensitive headers
zuul.routes.auth-service.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

But I am not able to hit /ping or /login or /auth APIs all are giving 401.

Could someone please help me regarding the same.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: i think u added this `zuul.prefix=/api` in your config file, which does not match your endpoints

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth/**").permitAll()
```